# ubuntu bonding , how to auto switch to primary slave when available

Tags: network-bonding

https://www.unixmen.com/linux-basics-create-network-bonding-on-ubuntu-14-10/

I have configured the bonding with mode 1 :bond-mode active-backup.

```
 ln@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto ens33
iface ens33 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary ens33

#eth2 configuration
auto ens38
iface ens38 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Bonding eth1 & eth2 to create bond0 NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.199.71
gateway 192.168.199.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-updelay 500
bond-slaves none
```

ens33 is bond-primary.
when  ens33 is unavailable , ens38 start work  ,  then  ens33 is available , the network will not work . ping will failed.

```
From 192.168.199.71 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

how to resolve this?